# Remove trigger creation when changing an indexer mode

Tags: magento2.2, indexer, mview

I've disabled the `Magento_Bundle` module because I don't need it.
But now when I try to set the `catalogsearch_fulltext` index to `schedule` via cli:

`php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule catalogsearch_fulltext` I get an error :

> Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
>
> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'catalog_product_bundle_selection' doesn't exist, query was: CREATE
>   TRIGGER trg_catalog_product_bundle_selection_after_insert AFTER INSERT
>   ON catalog_product_bundle_selection FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT IGNORE
>   INTO `catalogsearch_fulltext_cl` (`entity_id`) VALUES
>   (NEW.`parent_product_id`); END

Tracked this down and apparently this happens because in the `Magento_CatalogSearch` module in `etc/mview.xml` file, there is this line specified for the index `catalogsearch_fulltext` `<table name="catalog_product_bundle_selection" entity_column="parent_product_id" />`.
removing the line mentioned above makes everything work as expected. Obviously I cannot remove the config setting.
Any ideas on how I can bypass it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this with a workaround.
I added an `after` plugin for the method `Magento\Framework\Mview\View::getSubscriptions` that removes the `catalog_product_bundle_selection` if the bundle module is disabled.

`di.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Mview\View">
        <plugin name="remove-bundle-dependency" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Mview\ViewPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

`[Vendor]/[Module]/Plugin/Mview/WiewPlugin.php` looks like this.

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Plugin\Mview;

class ViewPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList
     */
    private $moduleList;

    /**
     * ViewPlugin constructor.
     * @param ModuleList $moduleList
     */
    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Module\ModuleList $moduleList)
    {
        $this->moduleList = $moduleList;
    }

    /**
     * @param View $subject
     * @param $subscriptions
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterGetSubscriptions(\Magento\Framework\Mview\View $subject, $subscriptions)
    {
        if (!$this->moduleList->has('Magento_Bundle')) {
            unset($subscriptions['catalog_product_bundle_selection']);
        }
        return $subscriptions;
    }
}
```

Also posted this as an issue on the magento 2 repo:  [#19719](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19719)

Comment: You got the solution and post on  github., Excellent